# How to include a jsp file using a custom taglib?

Tags: java, jsp, tags, include, taglib

I am trying to include a jsp file using a custom taglib. I have all the taglib setup in place, but it shows the include statement instead of the jsp content.

```
public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
    JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    if (section != null && !section.isEmpty()) {
        sb.append("<%@ include file=\"defaultHeader.jsp\" %>");
    }
    try {
        out.println(sb.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Failed to generate the tag", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return super.doStartTag();
```

I am really new to taglibs, so any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set an attribute with the name of the file within **PageContext** and then create your include directive in the JSP

Something like this

```
pageContext.setAttribute("includeFileName", "YourFile.jsp path", PageContext.REQUEST_SCOPE);
```

Your JSP:

```
<%@include file="${pageContext.includeFileName}" %>
```

and then in your JSP, get that attribute and voula! 
You don't really need to add or write the hole JSP file into the writer

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, I just figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out using the pageContext :

```
 pageContext.include(ERROR_BLOCK_FILE_NAME);
```